# What's the best way to plug up a huge hole in a rim joist

Tags: repair, leak, sealing, pest-control

Every time it rains heavily I get some water inside my crawlspace. Checked outside and crawled under my deck to find this huge hole which is about 10 x 4 cm.

[image: Gaping hole]

It appeared that there used to be a piece of wood here, but it is now gone, as if a rodent or rot destroyed it:

[image: Missing piece of wood]

The picture above is on a dry day. I poured some water and it looks like the water lips up that piece of wood and into my crawlspace:

[image: Gaping hole when deck has water]

Checking where the gutter pipe goes into the deck, I can see it's not very well sealed, but does this matter?

From the top:

[image: Gutter pipe entering deck from top 1]

[image: Gutter pipe entering deck from top 2]

From underneath:

[image: Gutter pipe entering deck from underneath]

And here is a picture from further back to give more context with the hole in green and the drain pipe in full view:

[image: Context shot]

### Questions:

1. What the best way to seal up this hole in the rim joist such that water and rodents are kept out?
2. Do I need to seal where the gutter enters into the deck floor as well?

Comment: The last picture might be a problem.  Drain pipe sealing is usually not a problem, unless there is a clog/blockage in the pipe.  This is for pipe going down, not sideways.

Comment: Yes, that last pic looks like the pipe end is simply open...is that looking down, or up?

Comment: Thanks @crip659, the drain pipe just ends under my patio so I'll remove that end and clean it out. I'm more concerned for that huge hole leading into my home

Comment: The last pic is pointed up towards the patio floor @Huesmann. There's some extra funnel which I guess is supposed to catch drips. The pipe end is indeed open underneath my patio floor though. If you look at the first picture you can see it leading left, where it just ends.

Comment: Framing doesn't act as a water barrier. Ever. Deal with the water, not the framing. I'm confused about the downspout path and the patio. Does the patio extend _over_ the house framing?

Comment: That's right @isherwood , the patio extends over the framing. I've just attached a new image to give more context. Thanks for the point about framing and water barriers. I do however also want to deal with the framing, as this is also most likely the main entrance where mice are entering my home. I have wire mesh and steel wool on hand but not sure what to plug the hole with. It sounds from your perspective that a piece of wood cut to size would do, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, either fit a block of wood or staple up some wire fabric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked someone at Home Depot and they suggested to stuff the hole with as much insulation as I can, then place the steel mesh I had over it, then cover it with a vapour barrier.

What I ended up doing was stuffing it with as much insulation I could, then adding a layer of steel wool, then steel mesh.

I did not add the layer of vapour barrier because I did some more investigating with the water and it looks like this hole is not the source of the water in my basement. There must be a crack in my foundation because I temporarily protected this hole with a vapour barrier and ran some water. Hole was bone dry but my basement still leaked.

Took a closer look at the gutter end and it wasn't actually reaching a drain by just 5 cm or so. Replaced the gutter end with a 10 $ flexible spout and connected it straight to the drain.

[image: Fixed rim joist hole]